# Accessing Android Application from a 'normal' Java class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a difficulty with my database connection. I have a DataManager which creates the Database connection etc. I also created an Application class which creates this DataManager so the UI Thread can get the data. Now the problem is that there is a background thread which also needs access to the database, and I am not exactly sure how to do this (currently I get an error when trying to create a new DataManager in the AsyncActivity because the database was not closed (and this is correct, as the UIThread has it open).

So I thought that (and this might not be the right way to do it as it is a different thread) I would get access to the Application and use the same DataManager on a new session. But how can I get access to the Application from an 'ordinary' class without Context or Activity (I have done it before I think, but cannot remember).

The code of the background task is:

```
public class SyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private static final String TAG = "Sync";

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public SyncTask(Context aContext) {
        //this.activity = activity;
        this.context = aContext;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setMax(100);
        this.dialog.setProgress(0);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String errMessage) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (errMessage == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Update completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error...");
            alertDialog.setMessage(errMessage);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Progress Update: " + progress[0].toString());

        super.onProgressUpdate(progress[0]);
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try{
            publishProgress( new Float(50).intValue());
            iDomsAndroidApp app = ((iDomsAndroidApp) ?? cannot remember ??);
            DataManager manager = app.getDataManager();
            manager.updateData();

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "error", e);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you have Context? You are passing it to the constructor. If you need something more, you could pass that to the constructor as well, I imagine?

Comment: I do realise that, but thought there was a generic way. I can pass the Context to the background task. But how do I get the Application then, as the Context itself does not give the getApplication() and casting the Context to Application does not seem right (or is it?).

Comment: You can use getApplicationContext() method of any Context instance you have and cast return to YouApplication. It is absolutelly eligible.

Comment: Great, thanks, that seems to work. Do you like to formulate an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getApplicationContext() method of any Context instance you have and cast return to YouApplication. It is absolutelly eligible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ContentProvider` for accessing the database, it is thread safe and the preferred way to handle your data.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html